# Displaying a table from MySQL database onto webpage with Ruby Sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

I have a MySQL database that I would like to display its table onto a webpage using Sinatra. I would also like to sort the data based on the column as well. So kind of like content management. Does anyone know a gem or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a gem, but DataTables.js is what I used for this same situation. It's only a couple lines to add to your sinatra project and provides sorting and searching by default. https://www.datatables.net/